# Force dependency property to refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, itemssource

I want to force the binding of my Listbox to refresh its content.
My listbox is bounded to a dependency property:

```
<ListBox ... DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"/>
```

I want to refresh the listbox content when, for example, I press a button in such a way that the DependencyProperty MyList get is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make MyList an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1), or something else which implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged)

Then if you changed the contents of MyList the ListBox would be updated automatically

In this case you wouldn't even need to declare `MyList` as dependency property. A simple readonly property would be sufficient:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyList { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) as the container for the items you want to display in the ListBox. This will automatically trigger a refresh of the control when items are added or removed.

Since you now never need create a new collection (only refresh its contents), you can use a regular C# property for this.

Personally, I would abstract this out

```
private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _mylist = new  ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
public IEnumerable<MyItem> MyList => _mylist;
```

To refresh the list ...

```
_myList.Clear();
_mylist.Add( ... );
```

The control will still update, as it detects that MyList implements INotifyCollectionChanged, even though it is just declared as IEnumerable.

You should never use a DependencyProperty for the source of data binding - a regular property, combined with INotifyPropertyChanged is the preferred way for any properties that update their value. Take a look at the MVVM pattern as a way of separating the user interface from the remainder of the code.